# Split csv file in bash accord to column value

Tags: bash, csv

I've a CSV file like this:

```
file1

field1 field2 field3 field4 
000000 nodata NP1212 1.1212
000000 212344 NP1212 1.1232  
000000 343423 NX3212 1.2342  
000000 542346 NX3212 1.6345  
000000 nodata NZ3244 1.0345
```

It is tab delimited, with about 70000 rows, with 23 field and sorted by field3. How can I split it by rows to create this kind of outputs?

```
file1_NP1212

field1 field2 field3 field4  
000000 nodata NP1212 1.1212  
000000 212344 NP1212 1.1232  

file1_NX3212

field1 field2 field3 field4    
000000 343423 NX3212 1.2342  
000000 542346 NX3212 1.6345  

file1_NZ3244

field1 field2 field3 field4   
000000 nodata NZ3244 1.0345
```

Answer (score 2):

This `awk` command should do the trick:

```
awk 'NR==1{hdr=$0; next}
     {fn="file1_" $3; if (p != $3) {close(p); p=$3; print hdr > fn} print > fn}
     END {close(p)}' file1
```

Comment: This risks running out of file handles if you have more than a couple dozen distinct values in column 3.  If indeed the input is sorted, closing the previous handle when you see a new value should be straightforward.

Comment: Thank you, it does 90% of the work! It just throw away the header, how can I retain it?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the header line in every output file and be robust against running out of file handles, try this.

```
awk -F '\t' 'NR == 1 { header=$0; next }
    $3 != prev { close(handle); prev = $3; handle = "file1_" $3; print header >handle }
    { print >handle }' file1
```

This assumes the input is already sorted on field 3; if not, you will end up overwriting files with partial output.